# How to I get my Public Hash Keys

Tags: address, hash

I wanted to start using Tezos but I do not know where to get my public hash keys.

There is info given to "check your contribution" is not helping much. 
Also how do I "Check My Contribution" before I even started? I don't think I contributed, right?

I would like some help and clarifications please.

Comment: please clarify if you participated in the 2017 fundraise or are new, if youre new the get started lists the wallets to use to generate a new account

Answer (score 1):

The PDF you received from the ICO contains everything you need to activate your address, including your public hash (starts with tz1, tz2, or tz3).